# What is the best to pad a collection of children in JavaFx when using a StackPane?

Tags: java, javafx

Hi I am fairly new to JavaFx.  My question is I am looking for an easier way to pad the children in my stack pane.

Currently the way I am achieving spacing between the items (see picture below)  I am doing something like the following in code

```
    private StackPane pane = .............

    pane.getChildren().add(card);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    StackPane.setMargin(card,new Insets(0,50,0,0) );

    pane.getChildren().add(card2);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    StackPane.setMargin(card2,new Insets(0,70,0,0) );

    pane.getChildren().add(card4);
    pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    StackPane.setMargin(card4,new Insets(0,90,0,0) );
```

Is there a way to add all my children as a collection and specify the spacing between the children?

::::UPDATE::::
One thing I want to point out, the cards are created dynamically. The collection of cards can be anywhere from a count of 0-n.  So I will not know in advance how many cards I need to display at any given time.

[The effect I am looking for in a concise way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjSRp.png)

Comment: You could use css to position it.

Comment: you should look into the fxml files/fxml Loader, that way you can set the layout (and most style properties) in an xml style sheet, while you can obtain the Stackpane and its children as plain fields in a controller. (ps. Scene Builder is a handy tool to create the fxml files http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/get-started-tutorial/jfxsb-get_started.htm#JSBGS101)

Comment: @Isiva You cannot style "static properties" like `StackPane.margin` with css.

Comment: @n247z  I am using a fxml and a controller sorry if that wasn't clear ( I couldn't show the FXML annotation in my description).  I get what you are saying I can define the fields in my fxml and populate it from code that might be a good idea.

Comment: @Isiva thanks I am going to look at doing it this way